# Bulk rename Outlook Folders using replace strings

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook

I'm now tasked with a massive project to import and reorganize about 50 outlook pst archives (probably around 100-200GB) into a single library account for my freight forwarding company.

I'm using a Windows 10 Pro computer with Office 365 Business Premium installed on the local machine and Outlook is using a current "Exchange Online" version 15.20.xxxx.xx so everything is available in the cloud.

The importing of archives isn't a problem.

My problem is having to rename several thousand outlook folders so they are organized!

End Goal is to have all email folders renamed starting with the full file number our company software set for this shipment:

```
CHI-AE0xxxxx (air export)
CHI-AI0xxxxx (air import)
CHI-OE0xxxxx (ocean export)
CHI-OI0xxxxx (ocean import)
CHI-DO0xxxxx (domestic)
```

where the x's are numeric and must now be 6 numbers

Until now, there was no naming structure, so everyone uses whatever made sense in their personal brain. Here's some examples:

```
CHOIxxxxx
CHOI0xxxxx
CHIOIxxxxx
CHIOI0xxxxx
```

or just xxxxx (I'll know what prefix needs to get attached to this person's folders)

So basically what I'm wanting to do is replace "CHOI" or "CHIOI" with "CHI-OI" and then if there's 5 digits, turn it into 6 digits with a leading 0.

I'm very experienced with Excel VBA and Macros.
I'm pretty good at using Powershell with Excel and SQL Server Databases.

I have no experience with Outlook and/or attempts to manipulate it with external tools like VBA or Powershell, but I'm willing to learn!

Comment: What exactly is it you need help with though?   You need to try somethings out and then post with a specific question, whether it's how to rename a folder in Outlook (see eg. http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?58198-Rename-all-subfolders-of-Outlook-2010-folder-with-the-same-text-string) or how to normalize your existing folder names to the required standard (which is just plain VBA and not Outlook-specific)

Comment: Can you write a script that looks at every filename and outputs the current filename and the one that you would want it to be? That would be a good starting point. At least you would have something to post in the question so that someone might have some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Outlook VBA was the way to go for this task.

I finally found a great answer yesterday:

https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/batch-find-replace-specific-words-outlook-folder-names/

I had to modify the code a little by replacing:

```
Set objFolders = Outlook.Application.Session.Folders("Personal").Folders
```

With this so it searches / modifies only the subfolders within the folder I currently have selected:

```
Set objFolders = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders
```

Here's the (almost) finished code:

```
Public strFind, strReplace As String

Sub FindReplaceWordsinFolderNames()

    Dim objFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set objFolders = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders

    'You need to input the specific words for find and replace
    strFind = InputBox("Enter the specific words you want to change.")
    strReplace = InputBox("Enter the specific words you want to change to. (Case Sensitive)")

    For Each objFolder In objFolders
        Call ProcessFolders(objFolder)
    Next

    MsgBox "Complete!", vbExclamation, "Rename Folders"

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFolders(ByVal objCurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim objSubfolder As Outlook.Folder

    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(LCase(objCurrentFolder.Name), LCase(strFind)) > 0 Then
       'Find and replace the specific words
       objCurrentFolder.Name = Replace(LCase(objCurrentFolder.Name), LCase(strFind), strReplace)
    End If

    'Process all folders recursively
    If objCurrentFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
       For Each objSubfolder In objCurrentFolder.Folders
           Call ProcessFolders(objSubfolder)
       Next
    End If
End Sub
```

It doesn't have any error checking, so if I click cancel in inputbox or leave it blank and click ok, the macro will act like "" is the strFind, so it then turns all folder names into all lower case, lol.

I think adding this just after the 2 inputboxes will solve it, but I'll test that tomorrow:

```
    If strFind = "" Or strReplace = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This solution seems really good for me, as there are so many varieties of search strings I need to address, that hard coding each one would have been a nightmare. Instead, this will allow me to adjust on the fly to how each user's brain was working when they developed their personal naming structures over the years.

After seeing and using this, I then developed another macro to batch move everything from the selected directory to whatever folder I wish to merge them into ... to create my true library of files, but that's a different topic so I suppose you don't want that posted in here.